# How to replace the first element of every list in a list of lists?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

How to replace the first value in a list of lists with a new value?

```
list_of_lists = [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i"]]

new_values = [1, 2, 3]

for i in list_of_lists:
    for n in range(len(new_values)):
        list_of_lists[n][0] = new_values[n]
```

Desired output

```
list_of_lists = [[1, "b" ,"c"], [2, "e", "f"], [3, "h", "i"]]
```

Comment: i didn't downvote, but you'll get better results if you post correct code (those `a`, `b` wont compile as they're missing their quotes).  in fact, you could even run that, correct code, and show us the output or the error codes so that we might make suggestions.

Comment: Why do you show us a working code?

Comment: see, the idea is that, esp with Python, we can cut and paste the code into our own test file and tweak it so that it does what you want.  this also avoids wasting your time with people who tell you what to do, but are in fact wrong.  so... wins on both side.  anyway welcome aboard and don't mind the occasional rudeness too much, the site is generally very helpful, but people can occasionally be over-opiniated.  have a great weekend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is actually quite simple

```
list_of_lists = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
new_values = [1, 2, 3]  

for sub_list in list_of_lists:
    sub_list[0] = new_values.pop(0)
```

This iterates over the lists and removes the first value of new_values each time.

Comment: He iterates over the lists using i then doesn't actually use that. He could drop to just a single for loop (as the other answer suggests), but I'd argue it's more pythonic to iterate over the list directly and not introduce an index value if you don't need to.

Comment: Newer coders should be wary of the `.pop` method for lists, as it is destructive. Once this loop is done, new_values is left an empty list...

Comment: Yes, and also `pop(0)` is an O(n) operation, so this algorithm is unnecessarily O(n^2). Better to do something like `for lst, val in zip(list_of_lists, new_values): lst[0] = val`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
list_of_lists = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]

new_values = [1, 2, 3]

for n in range(len(list_of_lists)):
    list_of_lists[n][0] = new_values[n]
```

Also, as a quicker way to set up the list_of_lists, one could say:

```
list_of_lists = [list('abc'), list('def'), list('ghi')]
```

Further, to avoid modifying the OP's original code as much as possible, one could insert the following line at the top, to define each letter variable to have its own character:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i = list('abcdefghi')
```

Comment: Sure... The OP has two loops when he only needs one. I honestly didn't spend a lot of time looking at his logic, but the first loop doesn't do anything.

Comment: Looking more closely at his code, it works (excusing the fact that the letters 'a' thru 'i' aren't defined and are probably meant to be character literals... Other than that, although inefficient, it works. But it does waste an iterative loop. He could make it more efficient by removing the outer `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your code produces the correct output, but you don't need the outside loop:

```
for i in list_of_lists:
```

Notice you never use `i`.

But really, there's a better way. Python makes it simple to avoid awkward structures like `range(len(new_values))`. In this case you can simply zip your lists together and loop over that construct. This avoids the need to keep track of indexes — you just get the value and the list you want to alter in each loop iteration:

```
list_of_lists = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
new_values = [1, 2, 3]

for newVal, subList in zip(new_values, list_of_lists):
    subList[0] = newVal
```

`list_of_lists` will now look like:

```
[[1, 'b', 'c'], [2, 'e', 'f'], [3, 'h', 'i']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using enumerate to generate the index and list comprehension works too:

```
new_l = [[new_values[i]] + l[1:] for i, l in enumerate(list_of_lists)]

>>> new_l
[[1, 'b', 'c'], [2, 'e', 'f'], [3, 'h', 'i']]
```